# Probability and permutations problem

Tags: probability, permutations

Suppose we have to choose randomly a number between 0001 and 9999 where each number has an equally likely chance of being chosen. 'What would be the probability of choosing a number that represents a year in the calendar that has already passed?' 
My take is this, 
No. Of permutations from year 0001 to 1999 is 2×10×10×9=1800 and permutations from 2000 to 2016 is 3×1×2×7=35 is the probability 1800+35÷9000. If so the it's more that 1/5 but in India cars have number plates with 4 digit numbers assigned at random but such number seem to be very rare on a number plate. Why?

Comment: Any idea of your own on this?

Comment: @drhab I edited the post

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do it is this:

Between $1$ and $9999$ there are 9999 numbers inclusive. The calendar years that have passed are $1$ until $2016$. Therefore out of 9999 possibilities, you can choose 2016. Your answer is $\frac {2016} {9999}$ or $\frac {224}{1111}$ or $20.16$%.